# Count the number of non zero values in a numpy array in Numba

Tags: python, numpy, numba

Very simple. I am trying to count the number of non-zero values in an array in NumPy jit compiled with Numba (`njit()`). The following I've tried is not allowed by Numba.

1. `a[a != 0].size`
2. `np.count_nonzero(a)`
3. `len(a[a != 0])`
4. `len(a) - len(a[a == 0])`

I don't want to use for loops if there is still a faster, more pythonic and elegant way.

For that commenter that wanted to see a full code example...

```
import numpy as np
from numba import njit

@njit()
def n_nonzero(a):
    return a[a != 0].size
```

Comment: Please show at least one actual, complete piece of code you tried, including `import` statements, decorators and sample test harness.

Comment: [list(filter((0).__ne__, l)) for l in a]

Comment: @MarkSetchell Sure...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may also consider, well, counting the nonzero values:

```
import numba as nb

@nb.njit()
def count_loop(a):
    s = 0
    for i in a:
        if i != 0:
            s += 1
    return s
```

I know it seems wrong, but bear with me:

```
import numpy as np
import numba as nb

@nb.njit()
def count_loop(a):
    s = 0
    for i in a:
        if i != 0:
            s += 1
    return s

@nb.njit()
def count_len_nonzero(a):
    return len(np.nonzero(a)[0])

@nb.njit()
def count_sum_neq_zero(a):
    return (a != 0).sum()

np.random.seed(100)
a = np.random.randint(0, 3, 1000000000, dtype=np.uint8)
c = np.count_nonzero(a)
assert count_len_nonzero(a) == c
assert count_sum_neq_zero(a) == c
assert count_loop(a) == c

%timeit count_len_nonzero(a)
# 5.94 s ± 141 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
%timeit count_sum_neq_zero(a)
# 848 ms ± 80.3 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
%timeit count_loop(a)
# 189 ms ± 4.41 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

It is in fact faster than `np.count_nonzero`, which can get quite slow for some reason:

```
%timeit np.count_nonzero(a)
# 4.36 s ± 69.4 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Comment: Yeah, numba really excels when it sees a loop it can optimize. +1

Answer (score 3):

In case you need it really fast for large arrays you could even use numbas [`prange`](https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/latest/user/parallel.html#explicit-parallel-loops) to process the count in parallel (for small arrays it will be slower due to the parallel-processing overhead).

```
import numpy as np
from numba import njit, prange

@njit(parallel=True)
def parallel_nonzero_count(arr):
    flattened = arr.ravel()
    sum_ = 0
    for i in prange(flattened.size):
        sum_ += flattened[i] != 0
    return sum_
```

Note that when you use numba you normally want to write out your loops because that's what numba is really very good at optimizing.

I actually timed it against the other solutions mentioned here (using my Python module [`simple_benchmark`](https://github.com/MSeifert04/simple_benchmark)):

[image]

Code to reproduce:

```
import numpy as np
from numba import njit, prange

@njit
def n_nonzero(a):
    return a[a != 0].size

@njit
def count_non_zero(np_arr):
    return len(np.nonzero(np_arr)[0])

@njit() 
def methodB(a): 
    return (a!=0).sum()

@njit(parallel=True)
def parallel_nonzero_count(arr):
    flattened = arr.ravel()
    sum_ = 0
    for i in prange(flattened.size):
        sum_ += flattened[i] != 0
    return sum_

@njit()
def count_loop(a):
    s = 0
    for i in a:
        if i != 0:
            s += 1
    return s

from simple_benchmark import benchmark

args = {}
for exp in range(2, 20):
    size = 2**exp
    arr = np.random.random(size)
    arr[arr < 0.3] = 0.0
    args[size] = arr

b = benchmark(
    funcs=(n_nonzero, count_non_zero, methodB, np.count_nonzero, parallel_nonzero_count, count_loop),
    arguments=args,
    argument_name='array size',
    warmups=(n_nonzero, count_non_zero, methodB, np.count_nonzero, parallel_nonzero_count, count_loop)
)
```

Comment: Is it safe sharing `sum_` between parallel loop iterations? (I don't know much about the guarantees of parallelized Numba)

Comment: Yes, numba has a few reductions that it can safely parallelize. summation and multiplications are one of them. That's because numba realizes it can process in parallel using `sum_ = 0` for each and then just add these after each process finished. I also checked for consistency against `np.count_nonzero`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `np.nonzero` and induce the length of it:

```
@njit
def count_non_zero(np_arr):
    return len(np.nonzero(np_arr)[0])

count_non_zero(np.array([0,1,0,1]))
# 2
```

Comment: that [0] seems to be the thing that did it. Thank you very much!

Comment: Funny thing is that `np.nonzero` uses `np.count_nonzero` (at the c-api level) to determine the size of the arrays that it will fill on a second iteration.  I though the whole point to using `numba` was to be able to iterate with impunity. :)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I have made a mistake here, but this seems 6x faster:

```
# Make something worth checking
a=np.random.randint(0,3,1000000000,dtype=np.uint8)  

In [41]: @njit() 
    ...: def methodA(a): 
    ...:     return len(np.nonzero(a)[0])                                                                                           

# Call and check result
In [42]: methodA(a)                                                                                 
Out[42]: 666644445

In [43]: %timeit methodA(a)                                                                         
4.65 s ± 28.6 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [44]: @njit() 
    ...: def methodB(a): 
    ...:     return (a!=0).sum()                                                                                         

# Call and check result    
In [45]: methodB(a)                                                                                 
Out[45]: 666644445

In [46]: %timeit methodB(a)                                                                         
724 ms ± 14 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```