# Vectorization in a loop slower than a nested loop in numba jitted function

Tags: python, performance, numpy, vectorization, numba

So I am experimenting on the performance boost of combining vectorization and for-loop powered by `@njit` in `numba`(I am currently using `numba 0.45.1`). Disappointingly, I found out it is actually slower than the pure nested-loop implementation in my code.

This is my code:

```
import numpy as np
from numba import njit

@njit
def func3(arr_in, win_arr):
    n = arr_in.shape[0]
    win_len = len(win_arr)

    result = np.full((n, win_len), np.nan)

    alpha_arr = 2 / (win_arr + 1)

    e = np.full(win_len, arr_in[0])
    w = np.ones(win_len)

    two_index = np.nonzero(win_arr <= 2)[0][-1]+1
    result[0, :two_index] = arr_in[0]

    for i in range(1, n):
        w = w + (1-alpha_arr)**i
        e = e*(1-alpha_arr) + arr_in[i]
        result[i,:] = e /w

    return result

@njit
def func4(arr_in, win_arr):
    n = arr_in.shape[0]
    win_len = len(win_arr)

    result = np.full((n, win_len), np.nan)

    alpha_arr = 2 / (win_arr + 1)

    e = np.full(win_len, arr_in[0])
    w = np.ones(win_len)

    two_index = np.nonzero(win_arr <= 2)[0][-1]+1
    result[0, :two_index] = arr_in[0]

    for i in range(1, n):
        for col in range(len(win_arr)):
            w[col] = w[col] + (1-alpha_arr[col])**i
            e[col] = e[col]*(1-alpha_arr[col]) + arr_in[i]
            result[i,col] = e[col] /w[col]

    return result

if __name__ == '__main__':
    np.random.seed(0)
    data_size = 200000
    winarr_size = 1000

    data = np.random.uniform(0,1000, size = data_size)+29000
    win_array = np.arange(1, winarr_size+1)

    abc_test3= func3(data, win_array)
    abc_test4= func4(data, win_array)

    print(np.allclose(abc_test3, abc_test4, equal_nan = True))
```

I benchmarked the two functions using the following configurations:

`(data_size,winarr_size)` = `(200000,100), (200000,200),(200000,1000), (200000,2000), (20000,10000), (2000,100000)`.

And found that the pure nested-for-loop implementation(`func4`) is consistently faster (about 2-5% faster) than the implementation with a for-loop mixed with vectorization (`func3`).

---

My questions are the following:

1) what needs to be changed to further improve the speed of the code?

2) why is it that the computation time of the vectorized version of the function grows linearly with the size of the `win_arr`? I thought the vectorization should make it so that the operation speed is constant no matter how big/small the vector is, but apparently this does not hold true in this case.

3) Are there any general conditions under which the computation time of the vectorized operation will still grow linearly with the input size?

Comment: 'vectorization' in the classic `numpy` sense is to use the compiled `numpy` whole-array methods.  It still uses loops, they are just performed in compiled code, rather than at Python speed.  `numba` does this compiling for you, and it might actually create tighter C code when used loops.  With speed differences on the order of 5%, you are dependent on `numba` implementation details.

Comment: "Vectorized" commands are usually slower, since all of them has to be replaced by (multiple) for loops. But there is quite a lot to improve on func3. eg. disabling checking for division by zero, unnecessary exponentiation which can be replaced by multiplications. https://stackoverflow.com/a/57062221/4045774

Comment: Numba generally works best with explicit loops (NumPy functions can only be called, not optimized). See examples [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54832145), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57589358) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50224982). Also, you are calling `func4` twice in your code. You can try the `parallel=True` option of `njit` with `prange` to accelerate things, although it doesn't always make things faster.

Comment: @hpaulj Thanks for your reply. At this point I wonder if it is worth bothering writing vectorized codes again, when we can basically throw everything to the `numba` `njit` and enjoy speed boost. Granted in the development stage `numpy` is still useful for prototyping, but for a fully-optimized and highly-reusable end-product function I honestly don't see the point of doing it in `numpy` vectorized fashion anymore.

Comment: @max9111 Interesting. If I understand it correctly, does it mean I can get rid of the exponent to make it a recursive multiplication and gain some speed boosts?

Comment: Yes, I can add an answer if you like. But in your case it isn't that easy because of the underflow which has a high impact on performance.

Comment: @jdehesa Besides `parallel = True`, I wonder if stuff like `fastmath = True` provided in `numba` can speed up the code and can njit handle both `parallel = True` and `fastmath = True` at the same time?

Comment: @max9111 Do you mind shedding some lights on why underflow will have high impacat on the performance? To me, even if `(1-alpha_arr[col])**i` is 0 when i is large, it shouldn't really bother the performance of `w[col] = w[col] + (1-alpha_arr[col])**i`. Maybe I am misunderstanding something. Feel free to correct me

Comment: I am not sure about that, but this looks like an explanation for the poor performance https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denormal_number

Comment: @max9111 Really appreciate your info. Didn't know it could be such a serious issue. Seeing that it actually slows the performance in the functions, I wonder what's the "threshold" for such things happening in python though. Is it `1e-100`?

Comment: It should be 1e−308 for np.float64 according to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always think twice about complicated mathematical operations like (pow, divisions,...). If you can replace them by easy operations like multiplications, additions and subtractions it is always worth a try.

Please note that multiplying alpha repeatedly with itself is only algebraically the same as directly calculating with exponentiation. Since this is numerical math the results can differ.

Also avoid unnecessary temporary arrays.

**First try**

```
@nb.njit(error_model="numpy",parallel=True)
def func5(arr_in, win_arr):
    #filling the whole array with NaNs isn't necessary
    result = np.empty((win_arr.shape[0],arr_in.shape[0]))
    for col in range(win_arr.shape[0]):
        result[col,0]=np.nan

    two_index = np.nonzero(win_arr <= 2)[0][-1]+1
    result[:two_index,0] = arr_in[0]

    for col in nb.prange(win_arr.shape[0]):
        alpha=1.-(2./ (win_arr[col] + 1.))
        alpha_exp=alpha

        w=1.
        e=arr_in[0]

        for i in range(1, arr_in.shape[0]):
            w+= alpha_exp
            e = e*alpha + arr_in[i]
            result[col,i] = e/w
            alpha_exp*=alpha

    return result.T
```

**Second try (avoiding underflow)**

```
@nb.njit(error_model="numpy",parallel=True)
def func7(arr_in, win_arr):
    #filling the whole array with NaNs isn't necessary
    result = np.empty((win_arr.shape[0],arr_in.shape[0]))
    for col in range(win_arr.shape[0]):
        result[col,0]=np.nan

    two_index = np.nonzero(win_arr <= 2)[0][-1]+1
    result[:two_index,0] = arr_in[0]

    for col in nb.prange(win_arr.shape[0]):
        alpha=1.-(2./ (win_arr[col] + 1.))
        alpha_exp=alpha

        w=1.
        e=arr_in[0]

        for i in range(1, arr_in.shape[0]):
            w+= alpha_exp
            e = e*alpha + arr_in[i]
            result[col,i] = e/w

          if np.abs(alpha_exp)>=1e-308:
              alpha_exp*=alpha
          else:
              alpha_exp=0.

    return result.T
```

**Timings**

```
%timeit abc_test3= func3(data, win_array)
7.17 s ± 45.9 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
%timeit abc_test4= func4(data, win_array)
7.13 s ± 13.3 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
#from MSeifert answer (parallelized)
%timeit abc_test6= func6(data, win_array)
3.42 s ± 153 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
%timeit abc_test5= func5(data, win_array)
1.22 s ± 22.4 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
%timeit abc_test7= func7(data, win_array)
238 ms ± 5.55 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Comment: I am still amazed by the almost 20 times speed up. I actually spent sometime running your functions to see the performance myself, and got mind-blown. Looks like I have got a few places in my code base to check if there is any underflow handling overhead.

Comment: While it's true in math that repeated multiplication is the same es exponentiation with floating point numbers you will get different results (significantly different if the exponent is big). That's the same as with fastmath. If you don't care much about precision and only do the operations once that's fine but if you do repeated calculations on the same number the effects accumulate to the point where the results are likely too inexact. That's why I didn't add them (even if they are significantly faster) to my answer. Did you compare the results with the results from the original?

Comment: I'm a bit worried about the `np.abs(alpha_exp)>=1e-100` approach to avoiding underflow. While it avoids underflow it completely compromises the results. Instead of that check one might want to add a check if the value after the operation is `0` and then either error/warn about the issue or use the minimal double value afterwards (better than generating nans because of the division by zero).

Comment: I also noticed that the row and col were swapped at first and then got transposed back. Is there a significant performance gain from this? Do you mind shedding some lights on this?

Comment: @MSeifert I found while the performance differences among threshold = `1e-50`,`1e-100`,`1e-150`,`1e-200`,`1e-250`,`1e-300`, and `1e-305` aren't quite noticeable, they become apparent among `1e-305`, `1e-306`,`1e-307`, and `1e-308`. And the difference between `1e-307` adn `1e-308` are day and night. So for the accuracy-performance trade-off, I will go for `1e-305`

Comment: @mathguy Numpy arrays are C ordered by default (last dimension changes fastest). The memory access pattern should be according to the memory layout, which is important for performance. The operation at the end is no real transpose, it just changes the way you look at the memory (check ndarray.flags).

Comment: @max9111 I see. That’s why in my case, `result[col,i]` is used because the iteration over `i` is longer than that over `col`, so it is better to put `i` to the fastest dimension(in my case it is `axis=1`).

Comment: Another question. I saw `2.` and `1.` are used, is doing the operations on same dtypes have less overhead?

Comment: @mathguy Yes there can be an overhead. I have changed the array layout because, in the iterative approach I have to iterate over i in the inner loop.

Comment: @max9111 If high precision matters, would `2.` introduce more numerical error down the road compared to `2`? I heard in python floating points like `2.` could sometimes be evaluated as `2.0000000....0194`, aka not exactly `2` Feel free to correct me if I am wrong, because I don't know much about how `numba` handles `2.` vs `2` and I just want to make sure.

Answer (score 3):

It seems you misunderstood what "vectorized" means. Vectorized means that you write code that operates on arrays as-if they were scalars - but that's just how the code looks like, not related to performance.

In the Python/NumPy world vectorized also carries the meaning that the overhead of the loop in vectorized operations is (often) **much** smaller compared to loopy code. However the vectorized code still has to do the loop (even if it's hidden in a library)!

Also, if you write a loop with numba, numba will compile it and create fast code that performs (generally) as fast as vectorized NumPy code. That means inside a numba function there's no significant performance difference between vectorized and non-vectorized code.

So that should answer your questions:

> 2) why is it that the computation time of the vectorized version of the function grows linearly with the size of the win_arr? I thought the vectorization should make it so that the operation speed is constant no matter how big/small the vector is, but apparently this does not hold true in this case.

It grows linearly because it still has to iterate. In vectorized code the loop is just hidden inside a library routine.

> 3) Are there any general conditions under which the computation time of the vectorized operation will still grow linearly with the input size?

No.

---

You also asked what could be done to make it faster.

The comments already mentioned that you could parallelize it:

```py
import numpy as np
import numba as nb

@nb.njit(parallel=True)
def func6(arr_in, win_arr):
    n = arr_in.shape[0]
    win_len = len(win_arr)

    result = np.full((n, win_len), np.nan)

    alpha_arr = 2 / (win_arr + 1)

    e = np.full(win_len, arr_in[0])
    w = np.ones(win_len)

    two_index = np.nonzero(win_arr <= 2)[0][-1]+1
    result[0, :two_index] = arr_in[0]

    for i in range(1, n):
        for col in nb.prange(len(win_arr)):
            w[col] = w[col] + (1-alpha_arr[col])**i
            e[col] = e[col] * (1-alpha_arr[col]) + arr_in[i]
            result[i,col] = e[col] /w[col]

    return result
```

This makes the code a bit faster on my machine (4cores).

However there's also a problem that your algorithm may be numerically unstable. The `(1-alpha_arr[col])**i` will underflow at some point when you raise it to powers of hundred-thousands:

```
>>> alpha = 0.01
>>> for i in [1, 10, 100, 1_000, 10_000, 50_000, 100_000, 200_000]:
...     print((1-alpha)**i)
0.99
0.9043820750088044
0.3660323412732292
4.317124741065786e-05
2.2487748498162805e-44
5.750821364590612e-219
0.0  # <-- underflow
0.0
```

Comment: Interesting. Now that it is proven that in terms of performance njited loops is faster than numpy vectorization using CPU as the processors, I wonder if the same thing holds True using GPU instead? Also, are vectorized operations done in tensorflow also slower than the njited nested loops in numba?

Comment: @mathguy I'm currently on a computer without GPU and without tensorflow, so I don't know and cannot benchmark that.